# static const - top level of program does not allow static const - Dart

Tags: dart

I have looked at some other similar questions on SO, but they don't appear to address the following specifically.

What I want to achieve is to have compile-time constants that cannot be altered.

I have a program which I reorganized a little in order to de-clutter. The program had some const declarations prior to "main()". I moved these to a class, however it required that I declare them as "static const". I then thought, ok those other "const" declarations prior to "main()" should probably also be "static const". However when I attempted that, the Editor advised "Top-level declarations cannot be declared to be 'static'". EG.

```
static const int    I_CORRECT_YN       = 12;   // prompt nr.
```

So, I am a little confused. I thought that a "const" was static. Why do I have to declare "static" in the class? Why can't I declare a "top level" const as "static"? Also, what is the difference between:

```
static const int I_CORRECT_YN = 12;
const  int       I_CORRECT_YN = 12;
static final int I_CORRECT_YN = 12;
final int        I_CORRECT_YN = 12;    ?
```

What is the best or only way to declare compile-time values that cannot be altered?

I guess I am looking at the literal meaning, but I presume there is a more complex meaning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why do I have to declare "static" in the class?

Because instance variables/methods can't be `const`. This would mean their value could be different per instance, which can't be the case for compile-time constants. [(Source)](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch02.html#ch02-final-const)

> Why can't I declare a "top level" const as "static"?

The `static` modifier marks variables/methods as class-wide (same value for every instance of the class). Top-level stuff is application-wide and doesn't belong to any class, so marking them as class-wide doesn't make any sense and is not allowed. [(Source)](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch02.html#ch02-class-vars-and-methods)

> What is the best or only way to declare compile-time values that cannot be altered?

You are already doing it - add `static` when defining class constants. Don't add it when defining top-level constants. Also, use `const`. `final` vars aren't compile-time values.

> What is the difference between [source code with different constant definitions omitted]

`static const` and `const` is the pretty much the same, usage depends on context.
The difference between `const` and `final` is that `const` are compile-time constants - they can only be initialized using literal values (or expressions constisting of operators and literal values) and can't be changed. `final` variables also can't be changed after being initialized, but they are basically normal variables. This means any kind of expression can be used, and the value can be a different one for every class instance:

```dart
import "dart:math";

Random r = new Random();
int getFinalValue() {
  return new Random().nextInt(100);
}

class Test {
  // final variable per instance.
  final int FOO = getFinalValue();
  // final variable per class. "const" wouldn't work here, getFinalValue() is no literal
  static final int BAR = getFinalValue();
}

// final top-level variable
final int BAZ = getFinalValue();
// again, this doesn't work, because static top-level elements don't make sense
// static final int WAT = getFinalValue();

void main() {
  Test a = new Test();
  print(Test.BAR);
  print(BAZ);       // different from Test.BAR
  print(a.FOO);
  a = new Test();
  print(Test.BAR);  // same as before
  print(BAZ);       // same as before
  print(a.FOO);     // not the same as before, because it is another instance, 
                    // initialized with another value
  // but this would still be a syntax error, because the variable is final.
  // a.FOO = 42;
}
```

I hope this helped, and I didn't descibe it too confusing. :]

Comment: Yes, I think that explains it well thanks. I'll come back to it later.

Comment: Also note that final variables are initialized lazily on first access.